# Hide other div on click of any one div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to hide other opened div when i click on any one div (in my code it is .ac_container)
I have tried many things but they worked in button or  tag but it is not working in checkbox.

```html
<div class="container">
    <h1>Indian Food Categories</h2>
    <label class="ac_trigger" for="ac1">Beverages</label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="ac_hide"  onclick="showHide(this)" id="ac1" name="x1">
    <div class="ac_container" style="margin-top: -1px;">
        {% for a,b in beverages.items %}
        <table class="foods" style="border-bottom:1px solid #044b6b;width: 100%">
            <tr>
                <th style="text-align: left;color: #00FFFF;" id="{{b}}">{{b}}</th><td><input type="number" name="{{a}}" value="0" id="{{a}}"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    
    <label class="ac_trigger" for="ac2">Cereals And Grains</label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="ac_hide" onclick="showHide(this)" id="ac2" name="x1">
    <div class="ac_container"  style="margin-top: -1px;">
        {% for a,b in cerials.items %}
        <table class="foods" style="border-bottom:1px solid #044b6b;width: 100%">
            <tr>
                <th style="text-align: left;color: #00FFFF;" id="{{b}}">{{b}}</th><td><input type="number" name="{{a}}" value="0" id="{{a}}"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        {% endfor %}            
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please show what you've tried

Comment: ```<!--     <script type="text/javascript">
        function showHide(btn) {
            $(btn).next('.ac_container').toggle().siblings('.ac_container').hide();
        }
    </script> -->```

Comment: i have tried some more but right now i have this one

Comment: one is also that i will do with if else condition for every div but it is not efficient as per coding because right now i have around 35 div. but it works

Comment: Are you really saying that you tried to put `<script>…</script>` _into HTML comments_, and now you are wondering why it doesn’t do anything?

Comment: no after its not working i had put it in comments

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS property display: none in javascript.

you can try the following function.**(Edited)**

```
function showHide(tagData, divId){
          let allInputs = ['ac1', 'ac2'];
          let divToChange = document.getElementById(divId);
          divToChange.style.display = tagData.checked ? "block" : "none";
          if(tagData.checked){
          for(let i = 0 ; i < allInputs.length ; i++){
            if(tagData.id !== allInputs[i]) {
              let divToHideId = 'div'+allInputs[i].substr(allInputs[i].length -1)
              document.getElementById(divToHideId).style.display = 'none'
              document.getElementById(allInputs[i]).checked = false
            }
          }
          }
         };
```

you have to pass 'this' and 'div Id' with the function call so the function will know which div to hide/unhide.

Here is the full code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Static Template</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Indian Food Categories</h2>
      <div style="flex: 1">
          <label class="ac_trigger" for="ac1">Beverages</label>
          <input type="checkbox" class="ac_hide"  onclick="showHide(this, 'div1')" id="ac1" name="x1">
      </div>
      <div class="ac_container" id="div1" style="margin-top: -1px;display: none">
          {% for a,b in beverages.items %}
          <table class="foods" style="border-bottom:1px solid #044b6b;width: 100%">
              <tr>
                  <th style="text-align: left;color: #00FFFF;" id="{{b}}">{{b}}</th><td><input type="number" name="{{a}}" value="0" id="{{a}}"></td>
              </tr>
          </table>
          {% endfor %}
      </div>
      <div style="flex: 1" >
        <label class="ac_trigger" for="ac2">Cereals And Grains</label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="ac_hide" onclick="showHide(this, 'div2')" id="ac2" name="x1">
      </div>
      <div class="ac_container" id='div2'  style="margin-top: -1px;display: none">
          {% for a,b in cerials.items %}
          <table class="foods" style="border-bottom:1px solid #044b6b;width: 100%">
              <tr>
                  <th style="text-align: left;color: #00FFFF;" id="{{b}}">{{b}}</th><td><input type="number" name="{{a}}" value="0" id="{{a}}"></td>
              </tr>
          </table>
          {% endfor %}            
      </div>
      
  </div>  
  
  <script>
  function showHide(tagData, divId){
    let allInputs = ['ac1', 'ac2'];
   let divToChange = document.getElementById(divId);
   divToChange.style.display = tagData.checked ? "block" : "none";
   if(tagData.checked){
   for(let i = 0 ; i < allInputs.length ; i++){
     if(tagData.id !== allInputs[i]) {
       let divToHideId = 'div'+allInputs[i].substr(allInputs[i].length -1)
       document.getElementById(divToHideId).style.display = 'none'
       document.getElementById(allInputs[i]).checked = false
     }
   }
   }
   
  };
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Two things for working of the above code

1. If you specify checkbox id 'ac1' then the respective div id should be 'div1'. (if checkbox id is 'ac2' then div id will be 'div2')
2. You have to specify all checkbox IDs in the array at the start of the (showHide();) function.
   For e.g.

```
let allInputs = ['ac1', 'ac2'];
```

Comment: showHide(div1){
   let divToChange = document.getElementById('div1');

   let isOpen = divToChange.style.display;

   if(isDivOpen === 'block') divToChange.style.display = 'none';
   else divToChange.style.display = 'block';
}

Comment: like his div1 is the id i have created

Comment: and also i have to create different id for different div or the same beccause right now i have created the same id for both div and this is not working

Comment: @JashanDhiman I have made changes to the answer.

Comment: bro you tried this code because its not working like i want it is working like normal as in past

Comment: and bro i want that if i click on first it will open and after that if i will click on second then automatically first one goes in hide mode

Comment: @JashanDhiman I have again made changes to the answer as you wanted. So as soon as you click on the checkbox the other checkboxes will hide.

Comment: bro it is not working after 9th div why this is so

Answer (score -1):

I have a better solution. You can use tabs rather than doing what are you doing right now. Using tab you can replace current div content with another. It's easy and highly used.

Go to this [w3School link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp) for more understanding of what tab is. Hope this will help you out.